# CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints returns incorrect height when zoom out?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-text

I'm work with EGOTextView.I set the textContentView for viewForZoomingInScrollView.when I zoom it out and typing.It sometimes returns a incorrect height. Here is what I am doing:

```
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = _framesetter;
CFAttributedStringRef attributedStringRef=(CFAttributedStringRef)self.attributedString;
_framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attributedStringRef);

if (framesetter!=NULL) {
    CFRelease(framesetter);
}
CGRect rect = self.textContextView.frame;

CGFloat height = [self heightForAttributedString:self.attributedString forWidth:rect.size.width];
rect.size.height = (height + self.font.lineHeight * 2) * pageScale;
//pageScale is the scale scrollview end zooming


- (CGFloat)boundingHeightForWidth:(CGFloat)width {

CGSize suggestedSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(_framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), NULL, CGSizeMake(width , CGFLOAT_MAX), NULL);
return suggestedSize.height;
}
```

And I try this method too:

```
+(CGFloat)heightForAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)attrString forWidth:(CGFloat)inWidth
{

CGFloat H = 0;

// Create the framesetter with the attributed string.
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString( (CFMutableAttributedStringRef) attrString);

CGRect box = CGRectMake(0,0, inWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX);

CFIndex startIndex = 0;

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, box);

// Create a frame for this column and draw it.
CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(startIndex, 0), path, NULL);

// Start the next frame at the first character not visible in this frame.
//CFRange frameRange = CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange(frame);
//startIndex += frameRange.length;

CFArrayRef lineArray = CTFrameGetLines(frame);
CFIndex j = 0, lineCount = CFArrayGetCount(lineArray);
CGFloat h, ascent, descent, leading;

for (j=0; j < lineCount; j++)
{
    CTLineRef currentLine = (CTLineRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(lineArray, j);
    CTLineGetTypographicBounds(currentLine, &ascent, &descent, &leading);
    h = ascent + descent + leading;
    NSLog(@"%f", h);
    H+=h;
}

CFRelease(frame);
CFRelease(path);
CFRelease(framesetter);


return H;
}
```

But it seems always return a wrong height when you typing text after zoom.
Is there any other/better way to figure out the correct height for my attributed string? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also run in this case, solved it and wrote a category, which works for me in all cases. See my answer in If you use zero as height, it does not restrict the height to any height. I wrote a category for this issue, which works for me in all cases. See [iOS UITableView with dynamic text and images rendered together (NSAttributedString + images)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586190/ios-uitableview-with-dynamic-text-and-images-rendered-together-nsattributedstri/22104529#22104529)